# Does fidelity change with respect to time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement

I have a fidelity
$$e^{-|\alpha|^2}e^{-|\alpha\sin(t)|^2}e^{-|\alpha\cos(t)|^2}$$
where $\alpha$ (coherent state) is$\sqrt{5}$.
I plotted fidelity against time in a graph.

For $t=0$, I got $ F= 4.5\times 10^{-5}$

For $t=1$, I got $ F= 4.5\times 10^{-5}$

For $t=2$, I got $ F= 4.5\times 10^{-5}$

For $t=10$, I got $ F= 4.5\times 10^{-5}$

Why is my fidelity not changing? What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if the formula you've written is correct, then $$|\alpha\sin(t)|^2 +|\alpha\cos(t)|^2 = |\alpha|^2,$$ quite trivially, as you should be able to see. Therefore: $$e^{-|\alpha|^2-(|\alpha\sin(t)|^2 +|\alpha\cos(t)|^2)} = e^{-2|\alpha|^2}.$$

The resulting function is certainly not a function of time, since the time-dependence cancels out, leaving only a constant. Indeed, if you set $\alpha=\sqrt{5}$, you get $e^{-10} \approx 4.5 \times 10^{-5}$, as you have calculated.

In general, in such cases, actually *plotting* out the function is much more useful that calculating it for a couple of isolated values.

Comment: If it is time independent then I should get the same fidelity at both t=0 and t=1. But why am I getting different values?

Comment: Well, since I have no idea how you calculated it, I'd have to guess that it's some sort of rounding error by either your calculator or you! :)

Comment: Yes it is my calculation mistake. I have edited it. Thanks

Comment: @AEIOU You can, of course delete it, but there's no reason to. If you have a different question, you should ask another one. Editing the question to change its content after an answer has been accepted is generally frowned upon here, I believe...

Comment: I have a doubt. My initial state (t=0) is $|\psi\rangle$ = $|\alpha\rangle |0\rangle $ and Final state(t) is $|\chi\rangle= |i\alpha\sin(t)\rangle|cos(t)\alpha\rangle$. Now Fidelity should be 1 at t=0. How is it possible? My fidelity for both initial and final state is as mentioned above in the post

Comment: For fidelity at t=0 should I consider my initial state alone. Then inner product of |ψ⟩ is 1. Therefore fidelity at time t=0 is 1. Is it like this?

Comment: @AEIOU I'm sorry, I really don't have much of an idea. Perhaps if you can condense all of the doubts you have and post a new question, someone more experienced will be able to help.

Comment: Thanks. I have posted new question